# Changes in extent in sentinel image while calibration with snap tool

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, esa, sentinel-hub

i have a problem with the extents of my sentinel 1 image, actually as shown in the image above, am selecting the frame 1 to download from ESA, when i process the snap tool to calibrate i only get the frame 2 and my area is not totaly covered.

Can anyone help me with this?

I am new to radar imagery.

[image]

Comment: Are both images GRD products in IW mode? 
Can you share the full names of the products?

Comment: yes both images are in IW mode, here's the fall name : S1B_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180912T063657_20180912T063724_012678_017651_43A7

Comment: could it be that you used TOPS Split before or after the calibration? SLC data is organized in three swaths, but only few tools treat them separately. TOPS Split is one of them where you select IW1, IW2 or IW3 and retrieve only one third of the data. https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/acquisition-modes/interferometric-wide-swath

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies in the fact that you are using an SLC product. The IW mode is taken in the [TOPS mode](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-1-sar/products-algorithms/level-1-algorithms/topsar-processing) and requires TOPS processing. The process is to TOPS Split > Calibrate > TOPS Deburst.

The first step (TOPS Split)  requires an input on the `subswath` and `bursts` to use. It is probably that you are using the first or last `subswath` of the product.